# Can wildcards be used in Areas Extension?

Tags: untagged

[Areas Extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/areas) allows for areas to be defined by postal code. Is it also possible to define areas with postal codes that include wildcards? For example, I might want all the postal codes in the form A1A *** to be included in my area (otherwise, I have to list the thousands of possible postal codes). Has anyone got something working along these lines? None of the obvious wildcard options seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd either have to hack this line https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/areas/-/blob/e5579b00c9826cfb27cc1bfbdaca932e4cbc5864/Civi/Areas/DefinitionType/PostalCode.php#L40, or do like [this example](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/areas/-/blob/master/docs/developer.md), and in the getWhereClause() do that logic.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a LIKE is needed, I'll give that a try.